# how can i assign a value to a check box in erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view, helper

```
<%= f.check_box:TYPE %> AB <br><br>
```

I have used the above mentioned in my code and when i click submit it takes `1` if `checked` and `0` if `not checked`and it is stored in `db`. How can i store a `string` like `AB` if `checked` and `nil` if `not checked` and i want to store that string in `db` instead of `0 and 1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the definition of this helper method:

```
check_box (object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

So I supose you need something like:

```
<%= check_box :type, {}, "AB", "nil" %> AB <br><br>
```

But in your rails application you get string `'AB'` and string `'nil'`, that how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Rails 3.2 @ http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html
check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")

ex.
    <%= f.check_box( :type, {}, "yes", "no") %>